# Custome fields in Work items under Boards

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I have created 2 teams in project configuration. That is visible in Area under workitems. I created a custom field called Agile teams and I want to put those items from Area into Agile Teams. That is my criteria.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to copy the value from Area to Agile Teams with Excel or CSV. For example:

1.Create a query and find the work items you need.

2.Change column options and add Area Path and Agile Teams columns.

3.Save your query and export it to CSV.

4.Copy the value from Area Path to Agile Teams in CSV file.

5.Import work items with your CSV file.

Comment: How can we create query. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) and filter out the work items you want to change the value of Agile Teams.

Comment: Sure. Thank you.